# Uneven pivot without aggregation (filling in the blanks)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

### Header: user,  status, value

row1: u1,A,3

row2: u1,B,5

row3: u1,B,2

row4, u2,A,4

row5: u2,C,8

and I want the output to be a crosstab with NULL if there are not sufficient values from one user to another. In the example the output would be:

### Header: status, u1, u2

row1: A,3,4

row2: B, 5, NULL

row3: B, 2, NULL

row4: C, NULL, 8

(I am using SQL Server 2016.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear if you needed Dynamic (i.e. user columns).  Small matter if needed.

**Example**

```
Select [Status]       
      ,u1 = max(case when [user]='u1' then Value end)
      ,u2 = max(case when [user]='u2' then Value end)
 From ( 
        Select *
              ,Grp = Value - Row_Number() over (Partition By [Status] Order by Value)
         From  YourTable
      ) A
 Group By [Status],[Grp]
 Order By 1,2,3
```

**Returns**

```
Status  u1      u2
A       3       4
B       2       NULL
B       5       NULL
C       NULL    8
```

> **EDIT - Dynamic Approach**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([User]) From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [Status],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select *
              ,Grp = Value - Row_Number() over (Partition By [Status] Order by Value)
         From  YourTable
     ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [User] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p
 Order By 1,2,3
 '
Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: Thank you John, this is great! What would change to make this dynamic?

Comment: @ReneGarcia I'll extend my answer in a bit.

Comment: @ReneGarcia Added a Dynamic Approach

Comment: @ReneGarcia fyi - the sub-query is essentially the core structure for a Gaps-and-Islands query

Comment: @ReneGarcia Happy it helped.